# Trying to Access Application Delegate Variables / Properties

Tags: objective-c, delegates, global-variables

I am using a variable/propery of my application delegate as a global.  (I don't want to deal with a singleton class.)

I am trying to write a #define statement in my Application Delegate class.  If I type:

```
  [UIApplication sharedApplication]
```

in my app delegate class, code hinting does not recognize sharedApplication.  But if I type the same thing in a viewController class, "sharedApplication" pops right up.

In order to define a NSMutableDictionary in my applicationDelegate.h (or .m?), I write:

```
#define MyDictionary [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] stateDictionary]
```

Then if I try to use it in another class:

```
[[MyDictionary objectForKey:@"California"] largestCity];
```

I get an error that MyDictionary must be declared first.  I am really confused about a lot of concepts here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that someone will answer this better, but here's a quick one:

Let's say your application is called myApplication. Assign "global" property to MyApplicationDelegate, and then it will be accessible from anywhere like this:

```
// get reference to app delegate
MyApplicationDelegate *appDelegate = (MyApplicationDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

Property *myProperty = appDelegate.property;
```

Also, make sure that you link to MyApplicationDelegate file in header:

```
#import "MyApplicationDelegate.h"
```

There's a longer debate if using "global" objects is good design in general, but I won't go into that now.

Comment: That works great.  Thank you.  Is there anyway to define it so I can access the variable without using your 2 statements?  Do I have to release them?  If I did release them would they it release my AppDelegates instance of the dictionary and delegate?

Comment: Also, in the first part of my question, what is the difference between the two appDelegates?

Comment: You do have to use those two lines, unfortunately. There are no real global variables that I know of, but then again I don't use them in my code. :)

Releasing: release them in class where you created them. If you created them in MyApplicationDelegate, for example, release them in dealloc method there.

App delegate question: start a new stackoverflow question. :) It's a topic of it's own...

Answer (score 2):

I always add a category to `UIApplication` such as this:

```
@interface UIApplication (MyAppDelegate)
+(MyAppDelegate*)sharedMyAppDelegate;
@end
```

This way I do not have to worry about type casts at all. I often define and implement this category in the same file as the `MyAppDelegate` class itself. So this is the header I `#import` all over. All you can add it to your *`MyProject`*`_Prefix.chp` file.

Singletons are not bad, if your architecture is properly layered *(And yes it is fully testable)*.